# SQL server failover Cluster not reporting correct patch version

Tags: sql-server-2008, versioning, cluster-computing, servicepacks

I've got a bit of an obscure problem and I'm hoping someone here can give me some pointers regarding it, I've exhausted everythign I can think of...

At the moment, I have a two node cluster setup (sql server 2008). I have patched this, as per the microsoft guidlines, to service pack 1. The issue is, when I connect to each node individually, I can see the version is 10.1.xxxx, but, when I connect to the cluster by it's name, it reports 10.0.xxxx (the pre-service-pack installation version).

I've tried restarting the cluster services, and also re-applying the patch (which is impossible, because the service pack installer reports the cluster is at 10.1.xxxx - sp1).

Any help/advice/ideas welcome.

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a microsoft support ticket for this, and had the issue corrected by an extremely helpful MS support engineer - sadly, I'm not sure of the details of the fix.

Dave